# Ford Focus won't crank no clicking light on dash come on.

Tags: ford, focus, no-crank-no-start

Okay so I have a 2000 Ford Focus 5 speed. I was coming off the interstate and hit a bump and the car shut off. All the light on dash come on even the radio but it won't crank. Not even clicking. I've changed the starter relay and tried crossing over the neutral lock switch but still nothing.

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at the wiring on the starter the S terminal wire may have come off.

Pull the starter relay.

Terminal 30 is fused battery power.
Terminal 87 is output to the starter S terminal.
Terminal 85 is power from the ignition switch in the start position.
Terminal 86 is PCM controlled ground with the neutral switch in between.

If you don't have power at terminal 30 check fuse 8 in the under hood fuse box.

This is unlikely but when the key is in the start position check for ground at the neutral safety switch. This should tell you if the anti theft system is working properly.

Also regarding the engine stall check the inertia fuel switch it's probably located in the passenger kick panel.